# Como mostrar uma mensagem de exceção se o usuário não verificar um radio button no Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, radiobutton

Preciso exibir uma mensagem de erro na tela se o usuário não verificar um radio button. Neste código, existem 13 radio buttons separados em 4 radio groups
Eu tentei usar try/catch e if/else, mas a tela não mostra o erro Toast.

Outra dúvida: sei que os grupos de rádio não permitem que uma pessoa escolha mais de 1 opção, mas como posso fazer um excepeiton que permite ao usuário escolher apenas 1 botão de um único radio group?

**Por exemplo: agora eu tenho que escolher pelo menos 4 botões (1 de cada radio goup), mas eu quero fazê-lo de forma que apenas um de qualquer grupo bom o suficiente para o código funcionar**

Aqui está o código

```
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content.PM;
    using Android.Content.Res;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using System.Collections;
    using Android.Support.V7.App;
    using Android.Support.V4.View;
    using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
    using Auth0.OidcClient;
    using Android.Content;
    using IdentityModel.OidcClient;
    using Android.Graphics;
    using System.Net;
    using System;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Text.Method;
    using System.Text;
    namespace whirlpoolapp
    {
        [Activity(Label = "whirlpoolapp", MainLauncher = true)]
        [IntentFilter(
        new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataScheme = "whirlpoolapp.whirlpoolapp",
        DataHost = "lucasmoreira.auth0.com",
        DataPathPrefix = "/android/whirlpoolapp.whirlpoolapp/callback")]
        public class MainActivity : Activity
        {
            private ArrayList enderecos;
            TextView queroreconhecer;
            TextView crie;
            TextView conquiste;
            TextView entregue;
            TextView viva;
            TextView comentar;
            EditText comentário;
            Spinner spinner;
            ArrayAdapter adapter;
            RadioGroup rdgcrie;
            RadioGroup rdgconquiste;
            RadioGroup rdgentregue;
            RadioGroup rdgviva;
            Button enviar;
            private Auth0Client client;
            private AuthorizeState authorizeState;
            ProgressDialog progress;

            protected override void OnResume()
            {
                base.OnResume();

                if (progress != null)
                {
                    progress.Dismiss();

                    progress.Dispose();
                    progress = null;
                }
            }

            protected override async void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
            {
                base.OnNewIntent(intent);

                var loginResult = await client.ProcessResponseAsync(intent.DataString, authorizeState);

                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (loginResult.IsError)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine($"An error occurred during login: {loginResult.Error}");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.AppendLine($"ID Token: {loginResult.IdentityToken}");
                    sb.AppendLine($"Access Token: {loginResult.AccessToken}");
                    sb.AppendLine($"Refresh Token: {loginResult.RefreshToken}");

                    sb.AppendLine();

                    sb.AppendLine("-- Claims --");
                    foreach (var claim in loginResult.User.Claims)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine($"{claim.Type} = {claim.Value}");
                    }
                }


            }

            private async void LoginButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
            {


                progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progress.SetTitle("Log In");
                progress.SetMessage("Please wait while redirecting to login screen...");
                progress.SetCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
                progress.Show();

                // Prepare for the login
                authorizeState = await client.PrepareLoginAsync();

                // Send the user off to the authorization endpoint
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(authorizeState.StartUrl);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
                StartActivity(intent);
            }

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
                {
                    Domain = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.auth0_domain),
                    ClientId = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.auth0_client_id),
                    Activity = this
                });
                //preenche o arraylist com os dados
                GetEmails();
                //cria a instância do spinner declarado no arquivo Main
                spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnDados);
                //cria textview
                queroreconhecer = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtReconhecer);
                crie = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCrie);
                conquiste = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtConquiste);
                entregue = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtEntregue);
                viva = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtViva);
                comentar = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtComentário);
                comentário = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtComentario);
                rdgcrie = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.rdgCrie);
                rdgconquiste = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.rdgConquiste);
                rdgentregue = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.rdgEntregue);
                rdgviva = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.rdgViva);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, enderecos);
                spinner.Adapter = adapter;
                spinner.ItemSelected += Spinner_ItemSelected;
                enviar = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
                enviar.Click += enviar_Click;
                void GetEmails()
                {
                    enderecos = new ArrayList();
                    enderecos.Add("Escolha um colaborador abaixo");
                    enderecos.Add("alexandre_bonfim@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("alexandre_t_pires@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("ana_carolina_simoes @whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("ana_claudia_s_belarmino@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("andre_costa@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("andre_l_teixeira@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("andreza_a_valle@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("anna_carolina_b_ferreira@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("bruno_b_souza@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("bruno_c_castanho@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("bruno_s_lombardero@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("caio_c_sacoman@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("carla_sedin@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("cassia_r_nascimento@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("celia_r_araujo@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("cesar_leandro_de_oliveira@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("daniel_b_szortyka@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("denis_caciatori@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("elisabete_c_ferreira@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("erick_c_senzaki@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("erika_g_souza@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("fabiana_monteiro@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("fernando_v_santos@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("gabriel_roveda@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("herivelto_alves_jr@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("jefferson_s_pecanha@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("josiane_a_teles@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("juliana_g_saito@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("juliano_ventola@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("leonardo_l_costa@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("leonardo_r_silva@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("lucas_m_santos@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("luiz_perea@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("norma_raphaeli@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("patricia_f_prates@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("priscila_l_dattilo@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("priscila_m_konte@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("reider_a_bernucio@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("renato_occhiuto@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("ricardo_a_fernandes@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("ricardo_matos_campaneruti @whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("rogerio_pagotto@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("ruben_c_anacleto@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("taise_azevedo@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("vinicius_marques_assis@whirlpool.com");
                    enderecos.Add("wanderly_t_limeira@whirlpool.com");
                }// fim getEmails

                void Spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
                {
                    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
                    string toast = string.Format("Colaborador selecionado: {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
                    Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    string texto = toast;


                }


            }
            void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {   try { 
                RadioButton rdbgrupo1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgconquiste.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                RadioButton rdbgrupo2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgcrie.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                RadioButton rdbgrupo3 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgviva.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                RadioButton rdbgrupo4 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgentregue.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                if (rdbgrupo1.Selected == false || rdbgrupo2.Selected == false || rdbgrupo3.Selected == false || rdbgrupo4.Selected == false)
                    {
                     string excecao = "Ao menos um botão de cada campo deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
                     Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        String emailescolhido = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        String campocomentario = comentário.Text;
                        string message = "Ao menos um botão de cada campo deve ser selecionado";
                        Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                        var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
                        //send to
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
                        new string[] { "" + emailescolhido });
                        //cc to
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
                        new string[] { "comite_clima_ti@whirlpool.com" });
                        //subject
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "SABIA QUE VOCÊ FOI RECONHECIDO?");
                        //content
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                        "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text);
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "" + campocomentario);
                        email.SetType("message/rfc822");
                        StartActivity(email);
                    }

                }
                catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
                {
                    string excecao = "Ao menos um botão de cada campo deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
                    Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                }


            }




        }
    }
```

Comment: "(...)mas eu quero fazê-lo de forma que apenas um de qualquer grupo bom o suficiente para o código funcionar" - Não seria então melhor ter apenas um *radio group*?

Comment: O problema de ter apenas 1 RadioGroup é que se alguém quisesse atribuir mais de um valor a outra pessoa, não poderia fazê-lo :(

Comment: @ramaral me indicaram esse possível solução:
public int RadioGroupIsChecked(RadioGroup radioGroup)
{
     //-1 means empty selection
     return radioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId;
}

//When user doesn't check a radio button, show a Toast
if (RadioGroupIsChecked(group) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(group2) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(group3) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(group4) == -1)
{
     string excecao = "Ao menos um botão de cada campo deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
     Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}

Comment: Como aceitou a resposta do Matheus pensei que ela tinha resolvido o problema. De facto pode usar `RadioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId` para verificar se algum dos RadioButton do grupo foi seleccionado. O seu valor será `-1` caso não haja nenhum seleccionado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você tem que usar `rdbgrupo1.Checked` e não `rdbgrupo1.Selected`.

Comment: Eu mudei para if (rdbgrupo1.Checked == false || rdbgrupo2.Checked == false || rdbgrupo3.Checked == false || rdbgrupo4.Checked == false)
                {
                    string excecao = "Ao menos um botão de cada campo deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
                    Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
Mas continua aparecendo o erro Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ocorreu

Comment: Meu cara, esse código ta todo estranho.

Se você quer ver se um radioGroup está selecionado basta você verificar se o rdgconquiste.CheckedRadioButtonId != -1